# Getting weird output after running UPDATE query in SQL (Oracle).

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The Dept table is as follows:

```
DEPT

DEPT NO NOT  NULL NUMBER (2)

DNAME             VARCHAR(16)

LOC                VARCHAR(13)

PHONE              NUMBER(10)
```

I'm executing the following query:

Update each row in DEPT to set the value for the PHONE column. Do not leave the phone NULL. Use different phone
numbers for each department.

So the above table with Phone column is the result of the above query. I tried to run the following query :

```
UPDATE DEPT
SET PHONE = 213-611-8209
WHERE DEPTNO = 10;
```

However, when I checked the contents after running, SELECT * from dept, I saw only "-8607" under the phone column. Why?

Que #2) Can I insert the phone number for all the rows in a single query?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle is doing some maths for you.

Comment: You probably meant to do: `UPDATE DEPT SET PHONE = '213-611-8209' WHERE DEPTNO = 10;`

Comment: `213 - 611 - 8209 == -8607`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `PHONE` column is defined as a `NUMBER` data type: 213 minus 611 minus 8209 = -8607.

You need to either define the `PHONE` column as a `VARCHAR2(12 CHAR)` and run this:

```
UPDATE DEPT
SET PHONE = '213-611-8209'
WHERE DEPTNO = 10;
```

Or leave it as a `NUMBER` data type and run this:

```
UPDATE DEPT
SET PHONE = 2136118209
WHERE DEPTNO = 10;
```

As for your second question, can you insert (or update) phone numbers in a single insert (or update) statement? Well that depends... where are these phone numbers stored? Or are you just randomly generating phone numbers for each row? The answer is "yes" - you could, but how to do this depends on many things.